# Using your Tor relay as a client for Torbrowser and other regular Tor traffic: Is this helpful or hurtful to your anonymity?

Tags: anonymity, configuration, relays, deanonymization, client

I run a relay off of my desktop computer, and currently have Torbrowser and Tox configured to use it as a client as well. I seem to remember hearing long ago that a client that also acts as a relay can potentially have better anonymity than a client alone. But lately I've heard a few mentions (mainly here and there in the tor-talk and tor-dev lists) that it might actually be hurtful to anonymity.

So, does anyone have any input on this? Should I be running a Tor instance separate from my relay instead?